Type C and PD Adapter Detect and Negotation
I am revising our prototype Texas Instruments BQ25713 battery charger board and I need to know a few information before production.

Can BQ25713 detect input and negotation via Type-C and Type-C cable?

BQ25713 does not includes D+/D- Pins, What would be the downsides of this?

The charger must be accepted by almost all adapters and input source, is it possible with BQ25713? if it is not possible, should we use BQ25792(it includes D+/D-) instead of BQ25713 OR can I use BQ25713 + TYPE C PD Controller like TPS25750?



TBH, I find the description "Supports USB2.0, [...] input current settings" a bit misleading - that probably means that the IC is compatible with USB-PD power profiles (voltage and current range). From my understanding the BQ25713 doesn't actually care where power comes from. To sink power from USB-PD sources you need a dedicated PD-sink controller (note: USB-PD comms take place on the CC-lines, not on D+/-).


No. As likely proven by the prototype.

There is no downsides unless you need them. And since you don't say what you are doing, it is unknown if you need them.

If you mean PD sources, none of the chips you mention have a PD controller to negotiate PD.


